# Nice proof of the Reidemeister-Singer’s theorem?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, 3-manifolds, heegaard-floer-homology

Is there a nice proof (preferably with pictures) of the Reidemeister-Singer theorem? I'd prefer some classical methods, perhaps in a book or lecture notes?
I want to learn how things are done.

Comment: There's a blog post giving some references to different proofs of Reidemeister-Singer here https://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/cerf-theory-proof-of-reidemeister-singer/ .

Comment: A proof, with references, is given in section three of this survey paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.0182.pdf